# IOS: change orientation of UITableView from horizontal to vertical

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview, orientation

i am working in a project in which i am using `UITableView` to display data. The orientation of my project is Landscape. now i want to add portrait orientation mode to my project so that any user can use app in portrait as well as in landscape mode.
Is there any code or method available by the help of which i will change the orientation of `UITableView` from horizontal to vertical??

i want the orientation something like this
[image]

[image]

Comment: What happens when you rotate your device? I mean from landscape to portrait.

Comment: it rotates well but i want to change the orientation on tableview from horizontal to vertical

Comment: Can you post the pictures in landscape and portrait?

Comment: i edited my question please check sample images

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just develop 2 different prototypes with unique identifiers, provide them in cellForRowAtIndexPath based on current orientation.

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    if (UIInterfaceOrientationIsPortrait(self.interfaceOrientation)) {

        LatestNewsCell *cell = (LatestNewsCell *)[tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:@"portraitCell" forIndexPath:indexPath];

        // configure cell

        return cell;

    } else {

        LatestNewsCell *cell = (LatestNewsCell *)[tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:@"landscapeCell" forIndexPath:indexPath];

        // configure cell

        return cell;
    }
}

- (void)didRotateFromInterfaceOrientation:(UIInterfaceOrientation)fromInterfaceOrientation
{
    [self.tableView reloadData];
}
```

In the case of the cell with more labels, you just create additional IBOutlets for these and reuse the existing ones for the labels that are used in both orientations.

Answer (score 1):

I believe you just need to setup your project to support portrait orientation. After that, your `UITableView` will rotate as you rotate your device or simulator.

I have created a simple project to test this. Check the [output](http://cdn.makeagif.com/media/10-22-2015/bX-opl.gif) here.

Notice that sometimes, the view correctly rotates, and sometimes not. Must be a bug.

Comment: my project support both orientations but all i want to is when i want to use app in portrait the header and cells of tableview will shows vertically not horizontally